# How to force everyone stop editing OneDrive shared excel workbook?

Tags: file-sharing, onedrive

A public shared Excel workbook of mine once turned-off/removed share-link is still NOT able to be opened by Excel even though I have turn off sharing, and remove the shared-link.

How can I force everyone to leave this file?

[image]

Comment: Same question. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The other user(s) must logout from:

1. MS Word (sign out)
2. https://onedrive.live.com
3. sign-out from **all** browsers you did use to login to OneDrive.